# Spring Framework - how to modify service attribute via web form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I use Spring 4 and Thymeleaf to build my application. I need store some data in session so I decided to create a session service. Now I would like to modify the service attibutes via web form. I tried to do like this:

**MyService interface**

```
public interface MyService {
    String getTitle();
    void setTitle(String title);
}
```

**MyService implementation**

```
@Service 
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) 
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    private String title;

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    } 
}
```

**Controller class**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "my_test_action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAction(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("service", service);
        return "my_view";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "my_test_action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postAction(MyService service) {
        return "my_view";
    }
}
```

**The view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form th:object="${service}" th:action="@{'/my_test_action'}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <input th:name="title" th:value="*{title}"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfotunelly after submitting the form I gave the following exception:

> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class [com.webapp.service.MyService]: Specified class
>   is an interface] with root cause 
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class [com.webapp.service.MyService]: Specified class
>   is an interface

If I wrote MyService class instead of MyService interface the problem would be solved. But the above code is only sample. In my real case I use many implementations of the service so I need to use interfaces.

Comment: Is MyService and MyServiceImpl in same package? Also can you share the part in dispatcher-servlet.xml where `component-scan` is used?

Comment: @Aditya Jain: yes, MyService and MyServiceImpl is located in the same package. Generally my application works fine. The exception is throw after I submit the form.

Comment: Since you have an Interface availble, try using `ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES` instead of `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS`

Comment: @Aditya Jain: Problem is not solved but probably you are  right. I use interface so I should use ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES, thanks.

Comment: How do you *bootstrap* spring ? Any `Configuration` or xml around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I modified postAction method to the following form:

```
public String postAction(WebRequest webRequest) {
    WebRequestDataBinder binder = new WebRequestDataBinder(service, "service");
    binder.bind(webRequest);
    return "redirect:/my_test_action";
}
```

Now It works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create instance of interface, that's why it throws an exception. When spring tries to call factory methods for each bean declaration, it fails because you declared interface instead of it's implementation.

some example:

```
<bean id= "myServiceImpl" class="some.package.MyServiceImpl"/>
```